# how to trigger event in MicroStrategy using api

Tags: api, microstrategy

I have a requirement where I have to run a MicroStrategy trigger which i need to run after a SQL job completes. What are options I can use and if I want to run this code what details needed.

i have gone through a link [https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/2020/RESTSDK/Content/topics/REST_API/REST_API.htm#:~:text=The%20MicroStrategy%20REST%20API%20is,client%20applications%20quickly%20and%20easily](https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/2020/RESTSDK/Content/topics/REST_API/REST_API.htm#:%7E:text=The%20MicroStrategy%20REST%20API%20is,client%20applications%20quickly%20and%20easily). but i have a limited knowledge of rest api .

Comment: You’re more likely to get an answer on SO if you provide an example of code that you’ve already tried. Simply asking someone to write code for you doesn’t usually get much response.

Comment: paulbailey sure , will include more details

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [latest documentation](https://microstrategy.github.io/rest-api-docs/getting-started/rest-api-families) doesn't cover the Events API, but the Swagger documentation does.

MicroStrategy's demo instance has the latest version of this: https://demo.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary/api-docs/index.html

and the endpoint you're looking for is `/api/events/{id}/trigger`.

(This answer assumes that you're running some sort of process externally to MicroStrategy, and then need to trigger an event to indicate its completion. The documentation covers how to retrieve and use an authorisation token to call this endpoint.)